# Chrome Rich notifications not working in legacy packed app

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, rich-notifications

With Chrome 28 google added new Rich Notifications.

I was trying to get it working with Chrome legacy packed app but that doesn't seem to work.
Google published [sample packed app](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/rich-notifications) that uses Rich notifications but as soon as you change packed app to legacy packed app you get an error at notification creation.

```
notifications.create: Unknown error. lastError:29 
set lastError:29
(anonymous function) sendRequest:46
forEach utils:21
chromeHidden.handleResponse
```

Here is this changed sample app that is not working any more.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3546822/rich-notifications-broken.zip

Only thing I changed was to replace:

```
"background" : {
      "scripts" : ["app.js"]
    }
```

with

```
"launch" : {
      "local_path": "window.html"
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS: Application has permissions for notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like only way for old legacy packaged apps is to use HTML5 Notification api. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification

Answer (score 0):

Legacy packaged apps are, as you say, legacy, and as such won't be getting new features. I don't believe you can upload them anymore to the Web Store, so you wouldn't be able to publish them even if they had the features you want.

Comment: But why is the old createHTMLNotification removed then if this is not supported? How can I make same notifications as before now in legacy packed app?

Comment: That feature was removed from Chrome. If you're interested in building an app that you can publish and that has all the features you want, look into non-legacy [packaged apps](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html).

Answer (score 0):

According to https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/common/extensions/api/_permission_features.json&q=_permission_features.json&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=420, rich notifications are only available to extensions and 'new' packaged apps. Legacy packaged apps cannot use them.

Comment: But why is the old createHTMLNotification removed then if this is not supported? How can I make same notifications as before now in legacy packed app?